# jQuery how to get the class of the table when clicking the tr

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

How can I get the class of the table when clicking the tr?
This is my code

```
<table class='table1' border='1'>
<tr class='graph1'>
    <td>Test1</td>
    <td><a class='viewHistory'>View History<a></td>
</tr>
<tr class='graph2'>
    <td>Test2</td>
    <td><a class='viewHistory'>View History<a></td>
</tr>
<tr class='graph3'>
    <td>Test3</td>
    <td><a class='viewHistory'>View History<a></td>
</tr>
</table>

<table class='table2' border='1'>
<tr class='graph1-1'>
    <td>Test1</td>
    <td><a class='viewHistory'>View History<a></td>
</tr>
<tr class='graph2-1'>
    <td>Test2</td>
    <td><a class='viewHistory'>View History<a></td>
</tr>
<tr class='graph3-1'>
    <td>Test3</td>
    <td><a class='viewHistory'>View History<a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

When I click on

```
<tr class='graph2'>
    <td>Test2</td>
    <td><a class='viewHistory'>View History<a></td>
</tr>
```

It should display `'table1'`
or if I click on

```
<tr class='graph3-1'>
   <td>Test3</td>
    <td><a class='viewHistory'>View History<a></td>
</tr>
```

It should display: `'table2'`

Take not that this is dynamic, its not only graph2 or graph3-1 will be clicked.

how would I do that using jquery?
Any help would be greatly appreciated and rewarded! Thanks!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jordanbaucke/fvmER/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use `closest()` to find the `table` parent. See also http://api.jquery.com/closest/

```
$('.viewHistory').click(function() {
  var classname = $(this). closest('table').attr('class');
  alert(classname);
}
```

Comment: This is working. Nice! 
I'm wondering why is it when $('tr').click() is being used, i'm getting an undefined result.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery('table tr').click(function(){
    //this is set to the row's DOM element
    jQuery(this).parent('table').attr('class');
});
```

See the [`jQuery.parent`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) for details.

Never used it personally so not sure about this, but [`jQuery.closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) may give better performance compared to [`jQuery.parent`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/).

Also, please note that the following code sample will attach `click` event for any table row in the document, so you'd better add some specific class to your tables (say `clickable_table` and use it like this)

```
jQuery('.clickable_table tr').click(function(){
    //this is set to the row's DOM element
    jQuery(this).parent('table').attr('class');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the .parent() function (if you want to click the a tag, use it twice)
and the .attr("class") to get the class. I think there is also a .class or something but not sure right now.